# PHP imap_reopen no error returned

Tags: php, imap

I have a script that connects to a mailbox.
I'd like to check if I can connect to a folder that does not exist, but `imap_reopen` does not return errors.

```
<?php
$imap_url = "{mybox.mail.box:143}";

$mbox = imap_open($imap_url, "Mylogin", "Mypassword");
if ($mbox == false) {
    echo "Opening mailbox failed\n";
}

$submbox = imap_listmailbox($mbox, $imap_url, "*");
if ($submbox == false) {
    echo "Listing sub-mailboxes failed\n";
}
else {
    foreach ($submbox as $name) {
        echo $name . PHP_EOL;
    }
}   

$test = imap_reopen($mbox, $imap_url . "INBOX.MBOX3") or die(implode(", ", imap_errors()));
if ($test == false) {
    echo "Opening submbox failed\n";
}

?>
```

Script output :

```
{mybox.mail.box:143}.INBOX
{mybox.mail.box:143}.INBOX.MBOX1
{mybox.mail.box:143}.INBOX.MBOX2
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Mailbox does not exist (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Do you have an idea ?

Regards,

Stiti

Comment: imap_reopen return false if it can't connect to your folder. You don't need any errors.

Comment: @RaphaëlGonçalves I think the problem here is that `"Opening submbox failed"` is not printed because `imap_reopen()` did not return `false` into `$test` as expected.

Comment: Yes Michael Berkowski, that's my problem. I can't know where reopen failed.

Comment: Whoops   - I didn't scroll right to see the `or die()`. That's your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement ending with `or die()` is actually terminating execution before the `if` test against the return value in `$test`.

```
$test = imap_reopen($mbox, $imap_url . "INBOX.MBOX3") or die(implode(", ", imap_errors()));

// This code is never reached because of die()!
if ($test == false) {
    echo "Opening submbox failed\n";
}
```

So just remove the `or die()` expression and your `if ($test == false)` will be evaluated.  I'll also use `===` here since it should return a true boolean:

```
// Call imap_reopen() without (or die())
$test = imap_reopen($mbox, $imap_url . "INBOX.MBOX3");
if ($test === false) {
    echo "Opening submbox failed\n";
}
```

You may alternatively use

```
if (!$test) {
    echo "Opening submbox failed\n";
}
```

Note about the PHP E_NOTICE emitted - if `imap_reopen()` emits that notice even when returning `false`, this is one instance in which you may want to use the `@` operator for error suppression since you are correctly testing for errors in your `if` block.

```
// @ is not usually recommended but if imap_reopen()
// prints an E_NOTICE while still returning false you can
// suppress it with @. This is among the only times it's
// a good idea to use @ for error suppresssion
$test = @imap_reopen($mbox, $imap_url . "INBOX.MBOX3");
if (!$test) {...}
```

#### Addendum after testing:

[Documentation on `imap_reopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-reopen.php) is slim and ambiguous stating its return as:

> Returns TRUE if the stream is reopened, FALSE otherwise.

Some testing seems to imply that opening a non-existent mailbox is not considered an error state for which it returns `false`. When opening a non-existent mailbox on an otherwise valid stream, `imap_reopen()` will still return `true` but populate an error in `imap_errors()`.

So you may check `count(imap_errors()) > 0` for errors after opening the faulty mailbox.  Couple that with a `true` return check, in case `imap_reopen()` does return a true error state.

For example my testing produces results similar to:

```
$test = imap_reopen($mbox, $imap_url . "NOTEXIST");
var_dump($test);
// bool(true);
var_dump(imap_errors());                                                  array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(28) "Mailbox doesn't exist: NOTEXIST"
}
```

You may work around this using logic to:

```
$test = @imap_reopen($mbox, $imap_url . "INBOX.MBOX3");
if (!$test) {
  // An error with the stream
}
// Returns true, but imap_errors() is populated
else if ($test && count(imap_errors()) > 0) {
  echo "Opening submbox failed\n";
  // Do something with imap_errors() if needed
  echo implode(',', imap_errors());
}
else {
  // Everything is fine -  the mailbox was opened
}
```

For what it's worth, `imap_open()` exhibits the same behavior. Successfully connecting and establishing the stream (your variable `$mbox`) is possible with a non-existent mailbox. The stream is created and valid, but `imap_errors()` will contain a message `Mailbox doesn't exist: <mailbox>`.

Comment: Thanks for your return! I added the 'or die' expression only for testing if it returned an error, but no. So I have the error using both your 2nd and 3rd sample of code. I tried the 4th, but I still have the same error. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: @Stiti_ odd, I will set up a test when I am near a proper computer

Comment: @Stiti_ Okay, I had a chance to test `imap_reopen()` and posted my findings above.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! I tried the test on count(imap_errors()), but even when there are no error, count returns 1. So I use is_array(imap_errors()) and now it's ok!